# Show public c# property description on hover in VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper, custom-data-attribute

When you hover over a property in VS it shows the datatype and the origin/name.
I would like it to show a description.

`///<summary>` only works in the intellisense when you browse your properties.

The `ComponentModel.Description` data attribute only works in the intergrated VS property window (IDE thing or what ever).

Is there a 3rd option to get to show it on mouseover?

[image]

If not, is there maybe a setting in ReSharper that does the trick?

Comment: Visual studio will show the `<summary>` in tooltip. Just checked it; and that works. So I'm not quite sure what you're asking about.

Comment: @SriramSakthival Alright. My VS must be bugged then.

Comment: If you're looking for `<summary>` of referenced assembly which you don't have code then you'll have to make sure you have [XML documentation file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7%28vs.71%29.aspx) for the assembly which you're interested in.

Comment: try disable resharper and try, that would work for sure.

Comment: @RohitPrakash tried that - still nothing. But thanks. Guess this forces me to install 2013 (or just wait for 2015).

Comment: @KasperSkov, I follow the ///summary approach in every api I write and it works 100%. At last  you can also try uninstalling resharper and rebooting before go for 2013/15.

Comment: Side note: Don't use "VS12" if you mean VS 2012 - VS2012's version number is 11, whereas VS2013's version number is 12.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you're right. Silly mistake

Comment: You can try ReSharper > Options... > Code Inspection > Enable code analysis ON and Color Identifierts ON, this will show R# tooltip...

Comment: @RicoSuter the color setting worked. Thanks alot. Post as answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `ReSharper > Options... > Code Inspection > Enable code analysis ON` and `Color Identifierts ON`, this will replace VS tooltips with R# tooltips...